# Is it possible to subscribe (by email) to posts in particular tag that have at least x upvotes?

Tags: support, subscription

I want to get popular questions in a particular tag. For example, questions with a score of at least X, or top N questions per day from popularity meter in top-left corner (but for 1 tag).

Is it possible?

Comment: No, in general, you can subscribe to the tag, but filtering is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not even an RSS feed for search results (which is understandable for the vast majority of searches).  The best you can do is probably to set up a script to email you the results of a search using the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search).

Comment: @BilltheLizard, good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You can only subscribe tags based their [newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=newest&pagesize=15), [featured](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=featured&pagesize=15), [recently active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=active&pagesize=15) and [highest votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=votes&pagesize=15).

For [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag in meta:
[image]

As Bill [pointed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189171/is-it-possible-to-subscribeby-email-to-posts-in-patricular-tag-that-have-at-le/189172#comment583684_189171), you can use https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search